# how can I remove blue color outline for input field in micromax a110 and sony ercisson mobiles

Tags: html, css

HI I am facing one problem that is in my application I have one input field and all andorid devices there is no outline color issue but for micromax a110 and sony ercission mobiles an blue color outline is coming. I don't know what is the exact reason.

The code is

html is
         
         
        
        .demo
        {
           outline:none;
           box-shadow:none;
        }

This is working in all the devices but above devices it is not working properly. i did not understand what is the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on some devices is due to the version of the browser. Before Android 4.0, Android Browser was used. Just use this:

```
input.demo:focus {outline: none !important; box-shadow: none !important;}
```

Comment: Yeah these devices are higher than 4.0. Then how to use outline for these devices.

Comment: If you're running Jellybean, then you're using Chrome for Android. This should work for that too.

Comment: These two mobiles running ice cream sandwich.

Comment: Hi Guys this is very important for my application. So please any one know about the approach please suggest any approach for this issue.

Comment: Try also adding `outline-color: transparent !important;`.

Comment: It is also not working I don't know what is the exact problem in these mobiles.

Comment: Are you using Android Browser or Chrome for Android?

Comment: I am using Android mobile browser

Comment: As of Android 4.1, Chrome is the only browser for Android. This code works in Chrome for Android.

Comment: But in these mobiles it is not working. These both the mobiles running ice cream sandwich.

Comment: If you're using Android Browser, there's nothing you can do. You should be having any problems in Chrome for Android with the above code.